# How to check if pyspark dataframe is empty QUICKLY

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to check if my pyspark dataframe is empty and I have tried different ways to do that, like:

```
df.count() == 0
df.rdd.isEmpty()
df.first().isEmpty()
```

But all this solutions are to slow, taking up to 2 minutes to run. How can I quicly check if my pyspark dataframe is empty or not? Do anyone have a solution for that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show how the dataframe is created? Dataframe .count() and .isEmpty() are **actions**. So when you call .count() or .isEmpty(), spark will execute all the transformations to create the dataframe

Comment: Hello @karatekraft thank you for your reply! To create the dataframe I'm reading it from a MySQL database using spark.read function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to check if your dataframe is empty or not after reading a table or at any point in time is by using `limit(1)` first which will reduce the number of rows to only 1 and will increase the speed of all the operation that you are going to do for dataframe checks.

```
df.limit(1).count() == 0
df.limit(1).rdd.isEmpty()
df.limit(1).take()
```

If you are just doing a data dependency check on a table and just want to know if table has data or not, it's always best to just apply limit 1 while reading from table itself for e.g.

```
df = spark.sql("select * from <table> limit 1")
```

With that being said about the efficiency of checking dataframe is empty or not, now coming on to which is the ***fastest*** way of doing it is using `.rdd.isEmpty()` compared to `count()`, `first()` or `take(1)`

Also if you see the backend implementation of `first()` and `take(1)` it's completely implemented on top of `collect()` which is mostly costly and should only be used when extremely necessary.

The below-mentioned time is based on reading a parquet file with `2390491` records and having `138 columns`.

```
>>> df.count()
2390491
>>> len(df.columns)
138
```

[image: Time taken by count(), take(), first()]

**Note:** These are the time taken after applying `.limit(1)` to the dataframe for checking whether the dataframe is empty or not.

Also lastly using, `df.rdd.isEmpty()` took the least amount of time `29ms` after reducing the number of rows to 1.
[image]

Hope that helps..!! :)

**UPDATE:** If you are using `Spark 3.x`, now you can directly use,

```
df.isEmpty()
```

This is the fastest of all for checking an empty data frame in Spark 3.x.

Comment: Minor correction: df.isEmpty() is only available from Spark 3.3.x

Comment: But this is still an action right? Because I checked in documentation page that this not an action unlike count()

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.isEmpty.html

I am using Spark 3.3.0 and the code performs an action when I tried the .isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `isEmpty` directly:

```
df = spark.read.csv()

if df.isEmpty():
  raise FileExistsError("Empty File")
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question? Please format your code and make sure to phrase your answer unambiguously